# google cloud pubsub node.js client not compatible with google cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

### Architecture:

We have an architecture using 2 pubsub topic/subscription pairs:

- Topic `T1` is triggered by a cronjob periodically (every 5 minutes for example). Subscription `S1` is the trigger for our cloud function.
- Topic `T2` serves as a queue for background jobs that are published by one of our services. Subscription `S2` is read by the cloud function on each execution to service the queued background jobs.

This allows us to control the frequency the background jobs are serviced independent of when they are added to the queue.

The cloud function (triggered by `S1`) reads messages from `S2` by [pulling](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull). It decides which background jobs are ready and upon successfully servicing the job, it ACK's the associated messages. Jobs not ready or failed are not ACK'ed to be serviced later.

### Issue:

We have issues using the official [node.js pubusb client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub) from google:

1. Sometimes ACK'ed messages re-appear (seeming infinitely). We verified the messages are acked before the ACK deadline and are sure we are calling `ack()` by investigating our logs.
2. Sometimes after the first execution (after re-deploying the function), subsequent executions never receive new messages. We can verify the messages are queued in subscription `S2` either by verifying the unacknowledged message count in stackdriver or by re-deploying the function and seeing the messages getting serviced.

We believe this is a problem with google's node.js pubsub client. The cloud function docs clearly state [not start background activities](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_not_start_background_activities). However, looking into the node.js pubsub client source, it clearly services acknowledgements in the background using timeouts.

**Is google's node.js pubsub client not compatible with google cloud functions? Google [recommends accessing the service API's only when a client library does not exist or does not meet other needs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview). Is running the client in a cloud function "other needs", requiring us to write our own client using the service API's?**

### Workaround attempted:

As a "workaround" we tried delaying the end of the execution of the cloudfunction to allow any "background" processes in the node.js pubsub client to complete, but this did not consistently eliminate our issue. It seems that pubsub client is not cloud function friendly and cannot recover from being stopped in between cloud function executions.

### Update Feb. 22, 2018

I wrote [an article on our blog](https://blog.hubwa.re/google-cloud-pubsub-background-job-queue-with-cloud-function-workers-78092ce5a8cb) that describes in detail *why* we used PubSub in this way and how we are working around the fact that node.js pubsub client is not compatible with cloud functions.

Comment: I made a similar [GitHub issue here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A developer from the node.js pubsub client [confirmed](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/60#issuecomment-364532641) that using the client to pull messages from a Cloud Function is not a supported use case.

The alternative is to use the [service APIs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview). However, the REST APIs have [their own caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706961/880509) when attempting to pull *all* messages from a subscription.

Answer (score 1):

How are you triggering your functions?

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background), if your function is consuming pubsub messages, then you should use the pubsub trigger. When using the pubsub trigger, the library is not needed. Simply call `callback()` at the end of your function, and the pubsub message will be properly acknowledged.

For what you intend to do, I don't think your current architecture is the proper option.

I would move your first step to Google App Engine with a [cron task](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/cron), and making this task simply move messages from `T2` to `T1`, leaving the function having the trigger `S2` and processing the message.

So, your jobs would be published on `T2`, and you'd have a GAE app with a pull subscription `S2` triggered by a cron task, and this app would re-publish the message to `T1`. Then your function would be triggered by a subscription `S1` to topic `T1`, and would run the job in the message, avoiding the extra-processing of importing the pubsub library, and using the product as expected.

Furthermore, I'm not sure how you are originally publishing your jobs to the topic, but [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/taskqueue/) are a good GAE (and [product-agnostic in Alpha](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/rest/)) option for rate-limiting tasks.

A GAE app only used for this (setting a 1 max instance) would be within the [always free limit](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits#gae_name), so costs would not be noticeably increased.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer! Our architecture seems to be unique, but the advantage is that we are decoupling the publishing of background jobs (`T2`) from when they are serviced (`T1`). This allows us to service the jobs in bulk to save resources. We are avoiding the GAE to not add any new maintenance burden (keeping all implementation in kubernetes + cloud functions). We use Kubernetes CronJobs to publish to `T1`. Finally, this solution keeps all implementation in node.js. Not python, go, or java that seem to be the clients for GAE and Task Queues. Is this a wrong use for PubSub?

Comment: You could use the alpha version of Cloud Tasks directly in k8s (you can request to join through [this link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g6yRocQ3wtdTArfO4JX8DoqOhYmsoTVgrlFnS0mV1bo/)). It's in alpha, so maybe not the greatest idea in prod, but you could look into it. You can also use the cron task, but I would still publish to `T1` -> cron job in k8s pulling and publishing to `T2` -> GCF with pubsub trigger on `T2`

Comment: ok, the goal being to eliminate the GCF from having to pull messages from PubSub? This is because you think having the GCF pull PubSub messages will continue to lead to problems?

Comment: I think there could be a workaround within GCF by blocking the callback until the message is acked (I could try to run some tests). I don't think it should lead to (more) problems in the future, but I think that this way of of regulating the rate of message consumption is a convoluted way of manually implementing what Cloud Tasks tries to accomplish. The best way it's possibly using Cloud Tasks (queuing directly your jobs as a task), but keep in mind that **it's still in alpha**, and that's always risk of having breaking changes. (With that said, GCF is also still in beta, so...)

Comment: I wrote [an article on our blog](https://blog.hubwa.re/google-cloud-pubsub-background-job-queue-with-cloud-function-workers-78092ce5a8cb) that describes in more detail _why_ we want to pull pubsub messages in a Cloud Function. It might add some additional clarity to my question.

Comment: This is very interesting. Thanks for writing the article! I understand that one of the reasons for this infrastructure is rate-limiting. Maybe lowering the [function invocation rate quota](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?metric=Function%20invocations%20for%20us-central1%20per%20100%20seconds) would be enough for limiting the rate? This would allow you to trigger the functions with the pubsub thread containing the jobs without having to control the rate using the cron.

Comment: Furthermore, for bucketing in time-zones, you could create different topics (jobs-EMEA, jobs-APAC, jobs-NA, ...), and at the proper moment (here a cron job would be useful) [update the function trigger with the time-specific  thread through an API call](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/patch).

Comment: calling `callback()` isn't an option in firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events

Comment: Weird, because [the examples provided in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#set_an_end_condition_to_avoid_infinite_retry_loops) for async (e.g. pub/sub) functions contain that call.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, I wanted better control over `.ack()`. Looking at the nodejs library from google, it would an option to refactor the `ack()` to return a promise so the function can wait for `ack()`to complete.

```
Subscriber.prototype.ack_ = function(message) {
  var breakLease = this.breakLease_.bind(this, message);

  this.histogram.add(Date.now() - message.received);

  if (this.writeToStreams_ && this.isConnected_()) {
    this.acknowledge_(message.ackId, message.connectionId).then(breakLease);
    return;
  }

  this.inventory_.ack.push(message.ackId);
  this.setFlushTimeout_().then(breakLease);
};
```

Comment: We changed our architecture to eliminate the need to pull messages from pubsub from within a cloud function. The link I added in the answer says it is not supported by Google :'-( The original use case was to use pubsub as a queue, we have replaced it with a collection in firebase firestore. It gives us much more control over messages in the queue and works nicely with cloud functions.