# PubSub REST subscription pull not returning with all messages

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

We use the [REST service API to pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull) messages from a PubSub subscription. Messages ready to be serviced are acknowledged, leaving other messages unacknowledged to be serviced during a later execution cycle.

During an execution cycle, we send a *single* reqeust to the [`pull` service REST API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull) with `returnImmediately=true` and `maxMessages=100`.

While testing we encountered a situation when only 3 "old" messages would be returned during each execution cycle. Newly published messages were never included in the request to `pull`. We verified new messages were successfully arriving at the subscription by monitoring the Undelivered messages in Stackdriver monitoring.

- **Does the `pull` REST API not include all undelivered messages?**
- **Does it ignore the `maxMessages` parameter?**
- **How should all messages, up to the maximum specified, be read with the REST API?**

### Notes:

We worked around the problem by sending 2 parallel requests to the `pull` API and merging the results. We found the workaround (requiring parallel requests) discussed [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1974).

### Update Feb. 22, 2018

I wrote [an article on our blog](https://blog.hubwa.re/google-cloud-pubsub-background-job-queue-with-cloud-function-workers-78092ce5a8cb) that explains why we forced to use the PubSub service REST API.

Answer (score 5):

A single `pull` call will not necessarily return all undelivered messages, especially when `returnImmediately` is set to true. The `pull` promises to return at most `maxMessages`, it does not mean that it will always return `maxMessages` if there are that many messages available.

The `pull` API tries to balance returning more messages with keeping end-to-end latency low. It would rather return a few messages quickly than wait a long time to return more messages. Messages need to be retrieved from storage or from other servers and so sometimes all of those messages aren't immediately available to be delivered. A subsequent `pull` request would then receive other messages that were retrieved later.

If you want to maximize the chance of receiving more messages with a `pull` request, set `returnImmediately` to false. This still will not guarantee that messages will all be delivered in a single `pull` request, even if `maxMessages` is greater than the number of messages yet to be delivered. You should still send subsequent `pull` requests (or even more ideally, several `pull` requests at the same time) to retrieve all of the messages.

Alternatively, you should consider switching to the [Google Cloud Pub/Sub client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs), which handle all of this under the hood and deliver messages to a callback you specify as soon as they are available.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is there a recommended number of request to send subsequently to be confident _most_ or all messages are retrieved?

Comment: Also, as I posted in my other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48623991/880509) and in my [github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/60) I have found that the [node.js pubsub client library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub) is not compatible with cloud functions, where my code is running... AFAIK because it does background activities, something that should be [avoided by cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_not_start_background_activities). Until confirmed, I feel forced to use the REST API's directly.

Comment: If you are constantly publishing messages, then you'll always need to be in a state of pulling, which means always creating subsequent pull requests. There isn't really going to be a way to guarantee that all or most messages are pulled at any time. You could potentially keep pulling until you've sent a sufficient number of requests that have returned zero messages (assuming you are use returnImmediatley=false) and that might be able to provide fairly good confidence that there are no more pending messages, but it will not be guaranteed.

Comment: ok seems logical. I should clarify our intention is not to guarantee that all messages are retrieved, only to be confident newly published messages will be retrieved even if there are older, unacknowledged, messages already in the subscription (messages that we intentional want to ignore until later). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wrote [an article on our blog](https://blog.hubwa.re/google-cloud-pubsub-background-job-queue-with-cloud-function-workers-78092ce5a8cb) discussing in more detail _why_ used PubSub in the way we did and the problem we faced pulling messages.