# Why Airflow PubSubPullOperator didn't pull max messages?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, publish-subscribe

I use PubSubPullOperator in airflow to pull messages from gcp subscription.

```
pull_messages_task = PubSubPullOperator(
        task_id="pull_messages",
        ack_messages=True,
        project_id=GCP_PROJECT_ID,
        subscription="k8s-sub",
        gcp_conn_id=GCP_CONN_ID,
        max_messages=50
    )
```

It works fine to pull messages from subscription and keep in Xcom.
My question is why PubSubPullOperator can't pull messages count equal to max_messages every time?

For example, I publish 250 messages to GCP topic. My Dag is run every minutes and pull 50 messages every time.

Below is process log from airflow:

```
[2022-05-17 14:53:04,630] {pubsub.py:536} INFO - Pulling max 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub
[2022-05-17 14:53:06,661] {pubsub.py:550} INFO - Pulled 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub

[2022-05-17 14:54:04,312] {pubsub.py:536} INFO - Pulling max 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub
[2022-05-17 14:54:06,239] {pubsub.py:550} INFO - Pulled 16 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub

[2022-05-17 14:55:04,055] {pubsub.py:536} INFO - Pulling max 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub
[2022-05-17 14:55:05,259] {pubsub.py:550} INFO - Pulled 4 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub

[2022-05-17 14:56:04,590] {pubsub.py:536} INFO - Pulling max 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub
[2022-05-17 14:56:06,527] {pubsub.py:550} INFO - Pulled 20 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub

[2022-05-17 14:57:04,083] {pubsub.py:536} INFO - Pulling max 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub
[2022-05-17 14:57:07,428] {pubsub.py:550} INFO - Pulled 38 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub

[2022-05-17 14:58:05,561] {pubsub.py:536} INFO - Pulling max 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub
[2022-05-17 14:58:07,431] {pubsub.py:550} INFO - Pulled 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub

[2022-05-17 14:59:04,348] {pubsub.py:536} INFO - Pulling max 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub
[2022-05-17 14:59:05,462] {pubsub.py:550} INFO - Pulled 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub

[2022-05-17 15:00:06,882] {pubsub.py:536} INFO - Pulling max 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub
[2022-05-17 15:00:08,710] {pubsub.py:550} INFO - Pulled 2 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub

[2022-05-17 15:01:03,519] {pubsub.py:536} INFO - Pulling max 50 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub
[2022-05-17 15:01:03,688] {pubsub.py:550} INFO - Pulled 20 messages from subscription (path) projects/production-1/subscriptions/k8s-sub
```

I'm pretty sure that each dag run time is under 1 minute. And 50 messages size is not over Xcom limit(48KB).

Does anyone has any idea about this situation? Or anyone knows how Operator decide how many messages to pull?

Many thanks.

Comment: This is a normal behavior using `PubSubPullOperator` since this Operator is a non-blocking task. If you want something that pulls every 50 messages you can use `PubSubPullSensor`.

Comment: @JoseGutierrezPaliza Thanks for the response. I changed PubSubPullOperator to PubSubPullSensor. But the results stay the same : ( The only different is that if there is no message in topic PubSubPullOperator will pass but PubSubPullSensor will wait.

Comment: @user2775128 did you find a way to get all the messages?

Comment: @SwapneshKhare not yet.

Comment: I have a similar problem, plus sometimes (with messages in the queue) the sensor seems to hang and keeps waiting for messages. I've tried to reduce the `poke_interval` but no success...

Comment: This stack overflow thread discuss the issue in detail. Basically this is the behavior of the PubSub Pull API, it will at maximum pull max_messages however this is not guaranteed, rather it tries to balance between time taken to retrieve max_messages and expected latency for that call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706127/pubsub-rest-subscription-pull-not-returning-with-all-messages

Answer (score -1):

It appears that this functionality originates from google's pubsub client library, and is not a feature/issue with the airflow operator itself.

From google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.client.Client#google_cloud_pubsub_v1_subscriber_client_Client_pull)

```
  The maximum number of messages to return for this request. Must be a positive integer. The Pub/Sub system may return fewer than the number specified.
```

Operator dependency
[PubSubPullOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/pubsub.html#PubSubPullOperator.execute) uses [PubSubHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/pubsub.html#PubSubHook.pull) uses [SubscriberClient](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.client.Client#google_cloud_pubsub_v1_subscriber_client_Client_pull)